# Como colocar logo em site?

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde galera!
Estou com uma pequena duvida em relação a inserção de imagem em uma página Html , bem , preciso colocar o logo de um site no topo da página , porém não quero que apareça o quandro branco de trás da imagem,preciso somente dos escritos , tentei aplicar transparência mas o efeito não ficou legal.
segue o código:

```
<!--header-top-starts-->
    <div class="header-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="head-main">
                <img src="/home/ronan/Downloads/Trabalhos 2016/web advocacia/foto.png"  width="398  " height="177" alt="Logo" />
            </div>
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Sua pergunta está muito ampla, e provavelmente será fechada. Que tal [edit] e adicionar mais dados? Como está seu código? Qual a extensão da imagem que está querendo colocar no site? Adicione essas informações e se possível a imagem, para que possamos auxiliar melhor. Aproveitando, faça um [tour] e entenda melhor o funcionamento do SOpt.

Comment: Só adiantando a possível resposta, edite a imagem e salve ela em PNG com o fundo transparent. Dessa forma não irá aparecer o fundo branco que mencionou.

Comment: A extensão seria exatamente o png , porém mesmo assim o fundo insiste em aparecer.

Comment: Teria uma pagina de exemplo para mostrar, assim ficaria mais facil te ajudar.

Comment: Pode postar a imagem junto? Provavelmente ela não está com o fundo transparente.

Comment: Bom vou mandar o link do site que já hospedei , porém ainda sem o logo no nome do cliente.

Comment: Esse é o site cesarfreitas.adv.br , se puderem me dar uma luz nisso fico agradecido .

Comment: Sem a logo não tem como lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde @Ronan, utilize um editor de imagens como o photoshop para remover o fundo branco, em seguida salve com o formato .png, depois carregue no html do mesmo jeito que você carregou, tem que funcionar. 
Abraço!